# How to add a mathjax equation into the html page using a javascript button

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

Say I wanted to generate a random fraction on a webpage using MathJax, I might write this:

```
function newFrac() {
    a1 = ran(1,20);
    a2 = ran(1,20);
    var txt = "$ \frac{"+a1+"}{"+a2+"} $"
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=txt;
}
```

where ran(1,20) calls a function to generate a random number. 
Then when the user clicked the button to make a new fraction it would write, say, `$ \frac{3}{7} $` on my webpage, but I don't want that, I want the equation displayed. How would I do that? How would I tell it to update after the javascript had changed the html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate math on the page after MathJax has processed it, you need to queue a call to `Typeset` via `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, el])` where `el` is the element containing the math that needs to be evaluated:

```
function newFrac() {
    a1 = ran(1,20);
    a2 = ran(1,20);
    var txt = "$ \frac{"+a1+"}{"+a2+"} $"
    var el = document.getElementById("a");
    el.innerHTML=txt;
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, el]);
}
```

See [Modifying Math on the Page](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html) for more detail.  See the section on [Manipulating Individual Math Elements](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html#manipulating-individual-math-elements) if you want to change an existing equation.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/c08a51r5w5tntb6/example.html

 - Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @captainjamie - You haven't included MathJax in your page.  See [this page](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html) for instructions on getting started.